# changing label text on selectedindexchanged of dropdown

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, drop-down-menu

I need the address (below the dropdown) to change as per the name that is selected in the dropdown... (they are all for one user only)...! (i donno why this keeps saying your post seems only code!!!!!!)

```
     public DataSet BindDropDownListToAUserAddress2()
    {
        UserFunctions objGetSession = new UserFunctions();
        string strSession = objGetSession.GetEmailFromSession();

        DataSet dsUserAddress = new DataSet();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]);
        con.Open();
        string strQuery = "(SELECT FirstName +' '+  LastName as FullName, *  FROM AUserAddress inner join AState on AUserAddress.State_ID = AState.ID inner join ACountry on AUserAddress.Country_ID = ACountry.ID inner join AUser on AUserAddress.AUser_ID=AUser.ID where AUser.Email='" + strSession + "')";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, con);
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        da.Fill(dsUserAddress, "AUserAddress");
        con.Close();
        return dsUserAddress;
    }



 protected void ddlName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet dsUserAddress = objBindDDL.BindDropDownListToAUserAddress2();
        string strSession = objGetSession.GetEmailFromSession();
        ddlName.SelectedValue = "FullName";
        if (objBindDDL.BindDropDownListToAUserAddress2() != null && objBindDDL.BindDropDownListToAUserAddress2().Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            lblDisplayFirstName.Text = dsUserAddress.Tables["AUserAddress"].Rows[0]["FirstName"].ToString();
            lblDisplayLastName.Text = dsUserAddress.Tables["AUserAddress"].Rows[0]["LastName"].ToString();
            lblDisplayAddressLine1.Text = dsUserAddress.Tables["AUserAddress"].Rows[0]["AddressLine1"].ToString();
            lblDisplayAddressLine2.Text = dsUserAddress.Tables["AUserAddress"].Rows[0]["AddressLine2"].ToString();
            lblDisplayAddressLine3.Text = dsUserAddress.Tables["AUserAddress"].Rows[0]["AddressLine3"].ToString();
            lblDisplayCity.Text = dsUserAddress.Tables["AUserAddress"].Rows[0]["City"].ToString();
            lblDisplayState.Text = dsUserAddress.Tables["AUserAddress"].Rows[0]["StateName"].ToString();
            lblDisplayCountry.Text = dsUserAddress.Tables["AUserAddress"].Rows[0]["CountryName"].ToString();
            lblDisplayPostalCode.Text = dsUserAddress.Tables["AUserAddress"].Rows[0]["PostalCode"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

[image: ddl]

[image: sql]

Comment: how do I make the address (below the dropdown) change according to the selected item in dropdown??

Comment: try setting AutoPostBack="true" for the dropdown list. And, am not really sure why you are trying to do this in your code ddlName.SelectedValue = "FullName";

Comment: first, just consider how many trips you are making to database, why you can't store the values in `Viewstate`.Second i hope `Autopostback` property is set to True in `.aspx` Page,Why binding is inside the `SelectedIndex` Changed Event.

Comment: I'll change the location of binding. AutoPostBack is true. Next?

Comment: use your id to fill the Label Text,query to viewstate based on ID inside the `SelectedChangedIndex` Event.

Comment: can you give me the code for what you are saying..? I dont know how to use view state...

Answer (score 0):

when you are binding data to dropdown list

```
 ddlStatus.DataTextField = "FullName";
 ddlStatus.DataValueField = "Id";
```

onselected index change event

```
int ID =Convert.Toint32(ddlName.SelectedValue)
```

by using this ID select only this ID Record from the dataTable and display